# Wifi Light not showing

Tags: wireless

My laptop is *Dell Latitude 3440* and has Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

The laptop shows no WiFi light even though I click <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: Please provide the diagnostic information as discussed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180